# DynamoDB data modeling

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Having a java BitSet representing user uniques, I would like to store into DynamoDB in order to use queries like "give me all BitSets from date X to date Y with a concrete key".

My first approach was to use a primary key representing what I really want to count, for example an action: "users-who-pay". Then the range key is the date and at finally I have the value into a binary attribute.

But probably it's not a good approach because I will have a few keys and lots of dates, so I would like to know if some one recommends me another approach.

Comment: You mentioned that BitSet is being used for representing user uniques.  Can you go into more details, I don't quite follow?

Comment: Sure, each user id is mapped into a  bitset position, when user do some tracked action I set the bit of position for user to 1

Comment: How big is the  bitset? In other words the number of unique users? How fast is it growing?

Comment: Let's suppose the size it's around 100k and it has random growing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A section in the DynamoDB documentation deals with a similar use-case. See [Take Advantage of Sparse Indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html)

> Take Advantage of Sparse Indexes
>
> For any item in a table, DynamoDB will only write a corresponding entry to a global secondary index if the index key value is present in the item. For global secondary indexes, this is the index hash key and its range key (if present). If the index key value(s) do not appear in every table item, the index is said to be sparse.
>
> You can use a sparse global secondary index to efficiently locate table items that have an uncommon attribute. To do this, you take advantage of the fact that table items that do not contain global secondary index attribute(s) are not indexed at all. For example, in the GameScores table, certain players might have earned a particular achievement for a game - such as "Champ" - but most players have not. Rather than scanning the entire GameScores table for Champs, you could create a global secondary index with a hash key of Champ and a range key of UserId. This would make it easy to find all the Champs by querying the index instead of scanning the table.

Such a query can be very efficient, because the number of items in the index will be significantly fewer than the number of items in the table. In addition, the fewer table attributes you project into the index, the fewer read capacity units you will consume from the index.

The example sounds very similar to your "users-who-pay" use case - only difference is that (replace "champ" with "paying user"). However, it is talking about a situation in which very few users are champs (and that's why it's OK to have "champ" as the hash-key - read more about good hash keys here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html). This could be remedied by saying that you have (say) 100 hash keys for champs - champ00, champ01, ..., champ99. One of the values could be chosen randomly at the time of writing the entry into DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `HashMap<String userId, Integer>`?  The good thing about this is:

1-  The size of the Map will be as big as it needs to be.
2-  You can count more then 1.  With BitSet you can only do 0 or 1.
3-  Maps are supported by DynamoDb natively.

EDIT:  Or if you do not need to count more than one, tan use a HashSet.  If a userId is in the HashSet then that means you got a hit.  If it is not in the HashSet, then it did not hit.

Comment: But that way the size will be bigger no? I don't need more than 0 or 1 to count uniques.

Comment: Then make it a HashSet.

Comment: I dont see the point to use a hashset or hashmap instead of bitset. In terms of size I think will be worst, so I will need a biggee provisional throghput, so more expensive. Am i wrong?

Comment: You would have to test it.  I think that you might be doing some premature optimization.  The way I see it is that you are creating a custom HashSet.  Please note that HashSet is baked into the JDK and has been scrutinized, optimized, and dissected by hundreds of developers that are better than us.

Comment: I'm using BitSet in fact for its operations, if I want to know how many users realized some action during 3 days, a simple operation AND give me that

Comment: So do you mean cast hashSet.size() to a BitSet and then do the operation? Seems like unnecessary operation for its benefits, or I'm wrong?